# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE node.js after adding Integer to create entry

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I use node.js express and sails.js to build my app.

When I added another input into my view it crashed on save.

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

```
create: function(req, res){
    var title = req.body.title;
    var body = req.body.body;
    var kUser = req.body.kUser;

    Knowlege.create({title:title, body:body, kUser:kUser}).exec(function(err){ // kUser:kUser seems to be the problem
        if(err){
            res.send(500, {error: 'Database Error'});
        }
        res.redirect('/knowlege/list');
    });
```

Error in terminal:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3) (...)
```

Model:

```
 module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    title:{
      type: 'string'
    },
    body:{
      type: 'text'
    },
    kUser:{
      type: 'integer',
      length: '11'
    }
  },
  connection:'MysqlServer'
};
```

Comment: What is `length: '11'`?  Do you mean `size: 11`?

Comment: yes size: 11 is whats needed in the mysqldb

Comment: Thank you, that was the cause and also Nir Levy is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Can't set headers after they are sent` means that you are trying to do something with your response after it was already sent.

Your problem is that you don't end the flow after sending the response in case of an error in your callback.
Since you don't, the redirection happens too, but the response was already sent.

Simply add `return` to exit the function:

```
if(err){
    return res.send(500, {error: 'Database Error'});
}
res.redirect('/knowlege/list');
```